# Is there a formula in Excel for define the background color of a cell?

Tags: excel, xls

Is it possible in Excel to set the background color of a cell with a formula?

One that I can write  `= BackgroundColor(RGB(1,1,1), "my value")`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this with a formula. You'll need VBA.

Comment: @Simoyw You can do this, but only with Conditional Formatting. With Formulas, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to answers here and my research, it's actually not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: The simplest way to do this is using conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as said with conditional formatting. For example if you want to change the colour of the cell A1 when A1 equals 3, you need to go to 'Home' then 'Conditional Formatting'. There you can choose the option 'new rule'. Note that you need to mark the cell A1 before doing this. Then you click on 'Format only cells that contain'. Then you choose 'equal to' and write in the box behind '3'. Then you can click on 'Format' and make it as you want it. If you then click 'OK' and write '3' in cell A1 the cell becomes how you formated it.